# Writing XML with VB 6.0

Tags: xml, logging, vb6

I need to write an error log to a XML file using Visual Basic 6.0.  Is there an easy way to do this?

The error log will contain the error number, source, desc, and a timestamp.

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: Thanks for the solutions.  I think I'll just make a simple string to store in a file.  Simply because, I wont have to worry about a large error log.  Each error will be logged into a separate XML file, which will be later stored in a DB and deleted.  Thank you for your help.

-Jeff (First time user)

Comment: Jeff note that who created a question, answer or comment is added by SO to the display, there is no need to sign them yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing the log-file only, I'd recommend just concatenating a string like this:

```
Public Function GetXmlEntry(errNumber as Long, description as String) as String
  GetXmlEntry = "<entry><error-number>" & errNumber & "</error-number><description>" & description & "</description></entry>"
End Function
```

Using the XML libraries is not necessary here, and will even hurt performance unnecessarily (i.e. without an advantage).

(**edit**) As it was pointed out in the comments, writing proper XML requires at least two additional steps for even one single entry: First, one needs to properly escape some special characters (should not be that hard); second, one needs to use correct (=same) encoding for all the XML file, consistent with the declaration in the header (for this my VB-Fu is not sufficient -- a little digging in the reference will help).

Comment: Avoiding the overhead of creating the XML parser just to create a simple XML document is very good advice!

Comment: @gimpf: Tweak function to handle proper encoding of description

Comment: "Wow, Thanks for the quick response."

Sincerest apologies to Binary Worrier and the entire community.

Comment: well-formed xml also has a root node, so the closing tag for the root node must be overwritten and then appended each time you add an entry as well.

Comment: I would not recommend this way. It may seem simpler at first but it's easy to break the XML document, e.g when "description" contains an invalid character such as '<'

Comment: (Continued:) And as Joel says the well-formedness is harder to maintain. That's why XML log files are generally a bad idea (Appending is expensive)

Comment: The idea to use XML for logging is debatable, yes.

I'd never write a closing tag for the XML file itself -- in case of a program crash this cannot be guaranteed nevertheless, so the reader has to take care of that.

Comment: Valid XML also must be Unicode, which is going to be difficult. I also agree that you shouldn't use XML for logging.

Comment: Unfortunately, XML is required.  However, the XML log file is temporary storage to ensure the information gets in the database.  Every error will have its own XML file and will be deleted once the error is logged in the DB.

Answer (score 4):

Probably it's best to use Microsoft's MSXML libraries to do that.

There is a sample in the knowledge base: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286817

Answer (score 2):

The Microsoft MSXML libraries are your first port of call, but there are things you need to consider before you decide to use it.

Appending error messages to an Xml using the MSML library will parse and load the Xml file every time you open it. As the Xml file grows you will find your app slows to a crawl.

It would be good if you could "just" append your error to the end of the file, however because of closing tags, this isn't straightforword, but it can be done.

If you have control over how the Xml file is created, you can work around this performance bottle next by splitting the Xml file into two, one with the header and one with the body of the xml. Then you can append to the end of the body file (by using an Xml writer class, or by simply appending text to the file).

See [Efficient Techniques for Modifying Large XML Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302289.aspx) for more info

However all this is unnecessarry if you're writing one error to the xml file, and the next error goes into another Xml file. In that case, go with MSXML

Hope this helps.